# Anyone have suggestions on how to make this Java switch case more efficient/readable?

Tags: java, performance, syntax, switch-statement

It is a pretty standard switch case used within a program that replicates an electric circuit. The main thing I am looking for is easier readability of the code and brevity, without disregarding efficiency.

edit: Didn't realize that I was unclear on the purpose of offset, the way offset works is that it will offset the input char by a number of characters equal to offset which is an integer. So for example if source is 'a' and offset is 2 this will return the value within the paths array at index 2.

```
char passCurrent(char source)
 {
     source += offset;

     switch(source)
     {
     case 'a':
         return this.paths[0];
     case 'b':
         return this.paths[1];
     case 'c':
         return this.paths[2];
     case 'd':
         return this.paths[3];
     case 'e':
         return this.paths[4];
     case 'f':
         return this.paths[5];
     case 'g':
         return this.paths[6];
     case 'h':
         return this.paths[7];
     case 'i':
         return this.paths[8];
     case 'j':
         return this.paths[9];
     case 'k':
         return this.paths[10];
     case 'l':
         return this.paths[11];
     case 'm':
         return this.paths[12];
     case 'n':
         return this.paths[13];
     case 'o':
         return this.paths[14];
     case 'p':
         return this.paths[15];
     case 'q':
         return this.paths[16];
     case 'r':
         return this.paths[17];
     case 's':
         return this.paths[18];
     case 't':
         return this.paths[19];
     case 'u':
         return this.paths[20];
     case 'v':
         return this.paths[21];
     case 'w':
         return this.paths[22];
     case 'x':
         return this.paths[23];
     case 'y':
         return this.paths[24];
     case 'z':
         return this.paths[25];
     }
     return '/';
 }
```

Comment: You'll probably get better results on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Post the declaration of source & offset, if these are string then how can you use char is switch?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis as-is, would be poorly received on [codereview.se], given the lack of context. `paths` is defined nowhere, and we don't know where the `source` is coming from (or its purpose) or what this `offset` might be, or why we're dealing with letters of the alphabet and whether it's a good way to solve the *actual* problem this code is solving. That said the *shape* of the question (e.g. "looking to improve readability+efficiency") does indeed look like a CR question that would be off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @NiranjanKumar `source` was already declared.  `offset`'s type is irrelevant, but we can assume it's something that doesn't cause an error at compile time.

Comment: @markspace This is the sort of question I'd expect from someone who doesn't realize that a `char` is a kind of integer.  Which I'm guessing is a fair fraction of newer programmers.  It's not obvious unless you learn it somewhere. This seems like a legit question to me.

Comment: use char-'a' to fecht the index

Comment: @ajb Thing is, `offset` **is** relevant. What if its value is 97 (`'a'`)? Then there is no point in a switch or a substraction, just `return this.path[source]`…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eliminate the `switch` and use subtraction after checking the range. Something like,

```
if (source >= 'a' && source <= 'z') {
    return this.paths[source - 'a'];
}
return '/';
```

**And**, we can shorten that further with a ternary like

```
return (source >= 'a' && source <= 'z') ? 
        this.paths[source - 'a'] : '/';
```

Answer (score 2):

A `char` is just a number; the meaning of the number has to do with how characters are laid out in Unicode (the numbers from 0 to 127 were defined a long time ago by ASCII, which got subsumed into Unicode).

Thus, if `source` is `'a'`, it actually has the integer value 97.  The letters from `a` to `z` are all consecutive in Unicode, so `b` is 98, `c` is 99, etc.

That means that if you want 0 for `a`, 1 for `b`, and so on, you can get it by simple subtraction.  Thus:

```
if (source >= 'a' && source <= 'z') {
    return this.paths[source - 97];
}
```

or, equivalently (and more readably):

```
if (source >= 'a' && source <= 'z') {
    return this.paths[source - 'a'];
}
```

since `'a'` is just another way to write 97.

Comment: Good explanation of why this is the way to go about it, I only chose the other answer because the ternary makes the code much cleaner

Comment: No problem.  I might have used the ternary myself, but it's a matter of style--I know programmers that don't like ternary operators.